# how to access all table field in datagrid of WPF in ADO.net

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datagrid, ado.net

I have use following code to access database,
but my datagrid do not display any records.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sanket;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM std", conn);
da.Fill(ds);            
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```